# Add custom error text for Commerce Coupon

Tags: commerce, 9

We have a coupon that is for shipping only. If user tries to apply it before they have entered address, then error is displayed: "The provided coupon code cannot be applied to your order".

Which is quite misleading in UX sense. Thinking to add custom error message, something like "You shall enter shipping address to use this coupon".

What is the best approach to do that?